# jQuery's pageY in IE9+ when scrolled

Tags: jquery, position

I've been trying to get the mouse's position relative to an element, but one of Microsoft's lovely failures (or jQuery's, who knows?) popped up.

When the page is scrolled, jQuery's `pageY` is right and whatsoever on Chrome, Firefox, and even IE8 (well, I expect it's the right behavior?). However, on IE9 and up, the `pageY` is relative to the users visible top.
... I'm bad at explaining things. Take a look at [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position). At the first example, compare the behavior between Firefox/Chrome/Safari/Opera and IE9+; the positions won't be the same (at least they aren't the same in my case).

A simplified version of my code in case it's needed, but I doubt it's helpful or anything in this case:

```
$("#element").click(function (e) {
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    console.log(e.pageX - pos.left, e.pageY - pos.top);
}
```

It might just be me missing something gigantic there, but it's been bugging me for hours now. Is there any way to fix this behavior in any way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try pageYOffset & pageXOffset.
Also, you don't bind the .pageXOffset to an event, but to the element - so do $(window).pageXOffset

Comment: But that gets the amount of pixels that's scrolled down and right. The point is that most browsers calculate it correctly, except for IE9 and up; it's not like I can simply add/subtract that. So would you mind explaining how I'm supposed to implement this?